# Where on Earth is the most windless lake with its own micro climate sea breeze?

Tags: geophysics, climate, geography, water, mapping

Would a circular lake have enough of sea breeze strong to create a gentle vortex in the center of the lake? Is there such a place on Earth where lake micro climate vortexes occur frequently? 
The Vortex would still be a breeze and not visible during normal Lake Breeze conditions.

https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/108896/could-a-city-be-built-out-of-balloons

[Where is the calmest place on Earth?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/13446/where-is-the-calmest-place-on-earth)

Comment: But sea breeze _is_ wind, so you are self contradictory. And what kind of vortex are you referring to?

Comment: Since the sea breeze is not a persistent phenomena, there is no such place on earth, nor any quantitative measure in determining a place that meets your criteria.

Comment: @Gimelist Your comments did help me, but are now detouring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wind Vortex on a Lake: the only thing I can visualize is a Tornado on a Lake.

Examples: [Pine Lake tornado](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pine_Lake_tornado), [Lake of the prairies Tornado](https://globalnews.ca/news/4346744/tornado-touches-down-at-lake-of-the-prairies/)

Technically speaking, a breeze/wind cannot be contained within a Lake, unless the lake is covered by mountain-cliffs or canyons at all sides. Maybe something like [Marietas Island's hidden beach](https://twistedsifter.com/2013/04/hidden-beach-las-marietas-islands-mexico/) or [Melissani Cave](https://twistedsifter.com/2012/08/melissani-cave-kefalonia-greece/), but much larger would sustain a self contained breeze.

Comment: so we can keep definitions in context ? A tornado over a water body is a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waterspout. Plus the question is center of the lake. It would help if you could address these issues.

Comment: the question is about self contained (circular) breeze

Comment: One part of the question. But my point is regards to your answer -In general people in the field refer to tornadoes over water bodies as waterspouts.

Comment: These are extreme condition but does answer. I was thinking under normal weather conditions. +1 from me.

Comment: @gansub not if it is a lake driven tornado not a tornado that happens to be over a lake.